# Bitorrent not working after windows update

Tags: windows-vista, firewall, windows-update, bittorrent

I installed the latest updates for MS windows vista. I was using torrent client Bittorrent simultaneously , when the updates were getting installed. i found the torrent client stopped working. i restarted my machine and i still find the same issue.

can someone help me resolve this issue .?

thanks,
vijay

Comment: You probably need to provide more detail than that to get useful answers. Which of the many bittorrent clients are you using? Which version? Define "stopped working" - does it error and not start, does it start and then error, does it start apparently OK but fail to transfer any data? If there are any error messages or other reports, what are they?

Comment: @David: There is a client called Bittorrent.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a full uninstall of your current torrent client, and then reinstall it. I recommend you to use [μTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads) but you can choose the one you like from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients).